# Highlight.js and Rails, page needs refresh - turbolinks again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My problem is pretty simple:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor-jquery
//= require_tree ./code
//= require turbolinks


hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="ui items" data-no-turbolink>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="index_post" data-no-turbolink>
      <%= link_to post.title, post, class: 'ui large header' %>
      <div class="date_created">
        <%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <%= simple_format(post.body) %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Highlight.js and default.css.scss are in their places inside assets folder and everything works successfully If I refresh the page. I tried to comment out the turbolinks line in application.js and everything is ok. How can I make it work by keeping turbolinks ?

This is a issue I meet in almost every project I create. A solution could be to include `data-no-turbolink` in the link's tag that opens the view that I have the problem, but it's a homepage (and other ones) that do not depend on a single link. Finally, I prefer an optimum solution than a hack.

Answer (score 6):

this one took me by surprise as well, however you need to account for highlightJS thinking that it has already been called in addition to TurboLinks bypassing the document.ready event. The code by @rsb only takes into consideration Turbolinks bypassing the document.ready event trigger. So you need `hljs.initHighlighting.called = false` in the answer from RSB:

```
ready = function() {
  hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
  hljs.initHighlighting();
}
```

NOTE: that I changed the call to `initHighlighting()` rather than `initHighlightingOnLoad()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor-jquery
//= require_tree ./code
//= require turbolinks

ready = function(){
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I have restarted the rails server and I am using the development environment with rake assets:clean. Web browser also refreshed. Isn't it a bad idea to include code in application.js ? Just asking.